# How to get all submenu data or attribute using map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the attribute **cat_id** of the **submenu** into an array when the user clicks on the main menu item.

this is the menu html:

```
<div class="CatBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-category-type="main" class="category" cat_name="DEPARTMENT STORES" cat_id="1" href="#cat01">DEPARTMENT STORES</a></li>
        <li><a data-category-type="main" class="category" cat_name="CONVENIENCE & SERVICES" cat_id="2" href="#cat01">CONVENIENCE & SERVICES</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="Telecome" cat_id="7" href="#cat01">Telecome</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="MOBILES" cat_id="9" href="#cat01">MOBILES</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="HYPER MARKET" cat_id="10" href="#cat01">HYPER MARKET</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a data-category-type="main" class="category" cat_name="FASHION" cat_id="3" href="#cat01">FASHION</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="Women" cat_id="11" href="#cat01">Women</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="Men" cat_id="12" href="#cat01">Men</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="Kids" cat_id="13" href="#cat01">Kids</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="SHOES & BAGS" cat_id="14" href="#cat01">SHOES & BAGS</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="WATCHES & ACCESSORIES" cat_id="15" href="#cat01">WATCHES & ACCESSORIES</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="BEAUTY & OPTICS" cat_id="16" href="#cat01">BEAUTY & OPTICS</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="Lifestyle & Sport" cat_id="20" href="#cat01">Lifestyle & Sport</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="Unisex" cat_id="21" href="#cat01">Unisex</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a data-category-type="main" class="category" cat_name="DINING & CAFES" cat_id="4" href="#cat01">DINING & CAFES</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="FOOD COURT" cat_id="17" href="#cat01">FOOD COURT</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="CASUAL DINING" cat_id="18" href="#cat01">CASUAL DINING</a></li>
                <li><a class="category" cat_name="CAFES & ICE CREAM" cat_id="19" href="#cat01">CAFES & ICE CREAM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a data-category-type="main" class="category" cat_name="ENTERTAINMENT" cat_id="5" href="#cat01">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
        <li><a data-category-type="main" class="category" cat_name="Home & Furniture" cat_id="6" href="#cat01">Home & Furniture</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is the jQuery:

```
$(".category").click(function() {
        main_cat = false;
        if (typeof $(this).data('category-type') !== 'undefined')
        {
            main_cat = true;
            arr = $(this).parent().children("ul li a").map(function(n) {
                return n;
            }).toArray(); 
        }
    return;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find`, not `children`.  The first parameter to map is also an index, the second is the element you're looking for:

```
arr = $(this).parent().find("ul li a").map(function(i, el) {
   return $(el).attr('cat_id');
```

Comment: In OP's case, there are no sub-submenus. But if there are, then `find` will retrieve _all_ descendants and return them as one big flat list. This may not be what you want. To limit the query to one level deep only, use this alternative selector: `">ul>li>a"`